# How to highlight background color of same names in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I want to change the background color of both duplicate values. If I use previous function it only change the background of next value but not current. How i change background color of all same same values.

How do I do this?

Comment: This is probably easest to do in the query, setting a flag on duplicates that can then be used to set the colour in the report. Doing it all in SSRS is going to be a challenge I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recreated your scenario using this dataset:

[image]

Now to solve your problem I've added a tablix:

[image]

Now for the cell [Value] that is selected in the above screenshot, go to `BackgroundColor` property and put this expression:

```
=IIF(
LookupSet(Fields!Value.Value,Fields!Value.Value,Fields!Value.Value,"DataSet10").Length>1,
"Red",
"Transparent"
)
```

> Note this expression will put the background color in red if the
>   number of occurences is greater than one. Otherwise it will
>   transparent color (none).

Replace `Fields!Value.Value` for the field you want to find multiple occurrences, and `DataSet10` for the name of your dataset.

It will preview the following tablix:

[image]

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: @JackSparrow: Nice, In that case you can select my answer as correct. [How to select an answer as correct](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)